# ¿Cómo manejar sesiones usando el API servlet en Java?

Tags: java, jsp, java-ee, servlets, session

Tengo en proceso una sitio web con Java EE, pero me falta manejar el *login* y *registro*.

Quisiera que me dieran una guía de cómo hacerlo mediante Servlets. Por ejemplo, que un .jsp `registro.jsp` envíe mediante un `<form></form>` hacia un `Servlet` llamado `RegistroServlet`. Esa parte de registro ya la tengo casi dominada, PERO quisiera manejar la sesión. Si es `administrador`, que el sistema me lo detecte, y si es un `usuario registrado` también. De manera que dependiendo de que tipo de perfil tenga, me redireccione a la página correspondiente

No se si sirva la información, pero tengo una base de datos con una tabla `usuario` y otra `TipoUsuario` con una relación @ManyToOne. La cree para que si se crea un usuario necesite el tipo de usuario también. ¿Cómo hago para manejar esa sesión? Soy nuevo en Java EE, he estado viendo videos, pero ninguno logra enseñarme lo que necesito, agradezco cualquier ayuda de antemano.

PD: ya en la tabla `TipoUsuario` tengo dos campos: *Usuario*  y *Administrador*

[image: Base de datos, con las tablas <code>usuario</code> <code>tipoUsuario</code>]

**EDIT**

registroUsuario.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilo.css">
    <title>Predicación pública - Registro</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="register_form">
        <center>
            <fieldset>
                <legend align="center"><h1><strong>¡Regístrate!</strong></h1></legend>
                <form action="" method="POST">

                    <label for="nombre"><strong>Nombre: <div class="asterisco">*</div></strong></label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="nombre" required> <br>

                    <label for="apeliido"><strong>Apellido: <div class="asterisco">*</div></strong></label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="apellido" required><br>

                    <label for="usuario"><strong>Usuario: <div class="asterisco">*</div></strong></label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="usuario" required><br>

                    <label for="contrasena1"><strong>Elija su contraseña: <div class="asterisco">*</div></strong></label><br>
                    <input type="password" name="contrasena1" required><br>
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Aceptar">
                </form>
            </fieldset>
        </center>
    </div>
</body>
```

*RegistroUsuarioServlet.java*

```
package com.carrito.servlets;

import com.carrito.model.TipoUsuario;
import com.carrito.model.Usuario;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class RegistroPublicadorServlet extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
 * methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String action= request.getServletPath();

    switch(action){
        case "/registroPublicador.":
        {
            String nombre = request.getParameter("nombre").trim();
            String apellido = request.getParameter("apellido").trim();
            String password = request.getParameter("passowrd");


            //implementación del método guardar
            Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
            usuario.setNombreUsuario(nombre);
            usuario.setContraseñaUsuario(password);

            TipoUsuario perfil = new TipoUsuario();
            perfil.setNombrePerfil("Administrador");

            usuario.setTipoUsuarioidTipoUsuario(perfil);
```

Comment: Hola brian, agrega tu codigo por favor para poder ayudarte de mejor forma

Comment: Lo agregaré @sioesi

Comment: Cómo ve, no he empezado con las sesiones, ya que no sé por dónde empezar. Me gustaría saber si me podría ayudar en esa parte. Una guía de cómo hacerlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener/iniciar la sesión del usuario, basta con llamar al objeto `HttpSession` desde el request:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
//colocar variables en la sesión
session.setAttribute("nombre variable de sesión", <objeto que quieres almacenar en sesión>);
//obtener variables de la sesión
//guarda todo como Object, el casteo es obligatorio
String nombre = (String)session.getAttribute("nombre");
```

Recomendación: Al parecer estás trabajando con Netbeans, el cual crea un método `processRequest` para ambos, el `doGet` y el `doPost`. Esto es **una mala práctica** y no deberías usarlo. El `doGet` sirve para pre procesar la vista, mientras que el `doPost` sirve para procesar la acción. Te recomiendo actuar directamente sobre cada método.

Answer (score 0):

Si esta usando JavaEE podria inclinarse mejor a usar JSF que ya tiene un manejo de sesiones maduro y segun el estandar de java enterprise es la implementacion de capa web oficial.

[Informacion oficial de java enterprise 7 jsf 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaph.html)

[Informacion java enterprise edition 7 jsf](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-intro.htm)

Si usa jsf entonces puede usar un objeto que se llama FacesContext que es el que maneja todo lo relacionado con sesion de la siguiente manera

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap()
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @Lcop. Sí, he oído muchas maravillas de JSF, y una vez termine esto, pues me voy a poner a estudiar cómo funciona ya que simplifica muchas cosas. Por ahora estoy haciendo este proyecto que tengo que entregar cuanto antes como parte de un curso. Así que lastimosamente tengo que usar JSP

Comment: @BrianMartínez es muy parecido de por si jsf viene de lo que se tiene en jsp, mira este post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419727/how-to-use-session-in-jsp-pages-to-get-information

Comment: Otra cosa @BrianMartínez revisa en el codigo que estas trabajando el objeto request, el debe devolver el objeto de sesion con request.getSession() y ese teoricamente deberia ser un map en el que se guardan objetos asociados a una llave, por ende cuando autentique, debera guardarlo en ese map y en las demas cargas debera obtener el objeto guardado en el map, si la sesion se termina posiblemente no habra objeto

Comment: ¿Podrías explicarme esa parte mejor?. Muchas gracias. Es que a penas estoy aprendiendo Java EE. Con getSession() inicio sesión con un objeto de sesión. Un poco de explicación me vendría bien mi amigo, si puedes

Comment: @BrianMartínez suponiendo que ya tiene una logica de base de datos para guardar y consultar datos entonces la gracia de la sesion estara en que al momento de realizar el login, se pueda guardar en ella algun dato que permita validar que la sesion no se ha vencido y que el usuario corresponde al que se logueo, previo a que al momento de hacer el login usted haga las validaciones pertinentes para determinar si el usuario es o no de su sistema, la idea es que usted guarde en sesion algun dato del usuario de forma que usted despues cuando vaya cambiando de paginas siempre valide en la sesion

Comment: Muy bien, ya entiendo la idea. ¿Podríamos continuar en el chat para que me muestres un ejemplo?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50092/discussion-between-brian-martinez-and-lcop).